# The callback of renderer is not called, what is happening?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, renderer

I am trying to have an html Select element, child of the component X, showing and hiding in response of a focus and blur event on that component X.
On the component X, I tried to set the listener with: 
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('focus', myFunc)

But not working. So I'm currently trying with this.renderer.listen, but not working neither. Here's the component TS and template:

Component.ts

```
import { Component, ContentChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { InputRefDirective } from '../input-ref/input-ref.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-with-suggestion',
  templateUrl: './input-with-suggestion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-with-suggestion.component.css']
})
export class InputWithSuggestionComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ContentChild(InputRefDirective)
  inputRef: InputRefDirective;

  hiddenSuggestions = false;

  focusListener: () => void;
  blurListener: () => void;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.blurListener = this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'blur', this.hideSuggestions.bind(this) );
    this.focusListener = this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', this.showSuggestions.bind(this) );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.blurListener();
    this.focusListener();
  }

  hideSuggestions(): void {
    console.log('hide');
    this.hiddenSuggestions = true;
  }

  showSuggestions(): void {
    console.log('show');
    this.hiddenSuggestions = false;
  }

  get suggestions() {
    return this.inputRef.data;
  }
}
```

And the component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>

<select *ngIf="(suggestions.length > 0) && !hiddenSuggestions" [size]="suggestions.length" style="color: black; position: absolute; display: block; width: auto; overflow: hidden" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions" value="suggestion.value">
    {{suggestion.text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Am I missing something obvious?
It also appeared that HostListener is not working with @Component but only with @Directive. Am I wrong with that too?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use ngAfterContentInit lifecycle hook...

Comment: It would be great if you make a small demo of your issue on stackblitz and provide the link

Comment: @Suryan Good call, it does make sense to wait for the content. Unfortunately I tried and the behavior is the same. I'll get a plunker ready.

Comment: The InputWithSuggestionComponent instance was unreachable, hidden by the its content (so the input). Set the listener on nativeElement.querySelector('input') rather than nativeElement fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The InputWithSuggestionComponent instance was unreachable, strangely hidden by the its content (so the input). Set the listener on nativeElement.querySelector('input') rather than nativeElement fixed it.